# Is my code failing because of my query, or on the database-end?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to query a MySQL DB to retrieve a list of variables. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
# import required modules
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='123.12.123.12',
                             port=3306,
                             user='db_user',
                             password='db_pass',
                             database='db_mcmods',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        #Setting variables as n,v,l to use later.
        sql = "SELECT `master_mods`.`Name` AS n, `master_mods`.`Version` AS `n`, `master_mods`.`Link` AS `n` FROM `master_mods`"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        numrows = cursor.rowcount()
        for x in xrange(0,numrows):
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            print(row[x])
```

This is the error that my DB throws:
(HY000/1045)

Things I have tried:

- Checked DB User Permissions
- Checked Connection Values
- Fixed Mismatched encoding between DB & Table
- Ran query through PHPMyAdmin to check validity

Here is my
[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMWkW.png)

Comment: I would suggest to first run the sql manually in MySQL workbench/cli

Comment: I ran the actual query thru PHPMyAdmin as well, it ran fine and found the rows. The problem seems to be happening with the actual connection. I've reached out to my hosting provider as I have enabled a wildcard for the ips/hosts allowed to connect.

Comment: `HY000/1045` is "access denied for this user".  Did you Google that?  Either you have the wrong username, the wrong password, or your database isn't set up to allow access from your IP address.

Comment: what is the output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'db_user'@'123.12.123.12';` ?

Comment: @AcaNg, you're on the right track, but 123.12.123.12 is the IP address of the db server in the example above, not the IP address of the client host. One needs to check the grants of `db_user` when they come from the client host.

Comment: @BillKarwin I understood. So the OP should ask the database admin to run the above query (replace `123.12.123.12` with the address of client) on server side and, if necessary, grant proper privileges to `db_user`. Right ?

Comment: Yes, or else the DBA may need to explain why that user@host combination is not allowed the privileges. There might be a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out and forgot to post the answer. It ended up being a weird error with cpanel, I had to reset my database user pw twice before it ended up working.

TL;DR Password issue. Appreciate the help everyone.